# Understanding definition of P-Value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I am trying to understand the following definition and wonder if there is a mistake in the notation.

"The p-value is the probability of observing a sample for which the difference between the $\mu_0$ and the sample mean $\hat{\mu}$ (assumption vs. data) is greater than $| \mu_0 -\hat{\mu} | $ in either direction, if the null was true."

I previously understood $\hat{\mu}$ to be "expectation"

Is expectation and assumption the same thing?
Should the text in brackets read "( data vs assumption )" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu_0$ is a number you put into your null hypothesis to test data against it and $\hat\mu$ is mean calculated from that data.

For example, imagine you have dataset that contains five numbers: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ and wish to test if mean (in whole population, this sample comes from) is $3.14$.

I above setting $\mu_0=3.14$ and $\hat\mu=3$.

> Is expectation and assumption the same thing?

Why you chose $3.14$ there? You expected that this is "true mean" (just like I expect my kids to clean a mess in their rooms)? Or maybe you assumed it (based on some expert knowledge)? It doesn't matter as long as $3.14$ is a number you put in null hypothesis. You may also say, this was just a guess, and this is OK too.

Of course, "expectation" can also mean "expected value of random variable" and be denoted by $E(X)$, but I assume this is not what you meant.

Comment: I was getting confused between expectation and estimation. Although estimation does not seem the right word here either since we are given the sample data.